# Slave Connection 1130

Tags: mysql, replication, my.cnf, centos, deployment

So I have a CentOS server that I have started to configure replication on my local machine.  When I take a look at the master server with `show master status;`, I get the following:

```
+------------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB        | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |   713473 | some_database       |                  |                   |
+------------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Then on my slave (which is actually MAMP PRO) I connect it to the master via the following:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='xxx.xxx.xxx.xx', MASTER_USER='my_slave', MASTER_PASSWORD='my_slave_password!', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001', MASTER_LOG_POS=713473;
```

And when I look at the log from MAMP PRO, I get the following:

```
170529  2:14:00 [Note] 'CHANGE MASTER TO executed'. Previous state master_host='', master_port='3306', master_log_file='', master_log_pos='4'. New state master_host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xx', master_port='3306', master_log_file='mysql-bin.000001', master_log_pos='713473'.
170529  2:14:42 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.000001' at position 713473, relay log './mysql-relay-bin.000001' position: 4
170529  2:14:42 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'my_slave@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400, Error_code: 1130
```

Before trying this method, I tried editing the `my.cnf` file for MAMP PRO and it didn't work.  Since then, I deleted the `master.info`, which was empty anyways, and tried this method.  What else can I try?  The log doesn't seem to give me any actual information, is there anywhere else I can look for info?

Answer (score 0):

first of all You need to test connection from slave to master
You can do this from command line (CMD windows)

```
mysql --host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx --port=3306 --user=my_slave --password=my_slave_password!
```

if it will be successful You will have normal mysql console

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 29
Server version: 5.7.15 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql>
```

if not, You must check:

- network connection
- my_slave user credentials, including allowed host, like my_slave%yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy where yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy - Your real ip address (in case of MAMP it could be ip of router). this is one of the frequent reasons for Error_code: 1130

if all ok, You can make dump direct from slave:

```
mysqldump --host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx --port=3306 --user=my_slave --password=my_slave_password! --single-transaction --master-data=1 --all-databases > c:\dumps\all_db.sql
```

restore dump on slave:

```
mysql --host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx --port=3306 --user=root --password=slave_root_password < c:\dumps\all_db.sql
```

login to mysql console and start slave:

```
mysql> start slave;
```

generally - that all

Comment: So in your answer, you are making the entire collection of databases slave to those on another server, correct?  I really only want to set it up for one database, is that possible?  And how?

Comment: in this case --all-databases must be changed to --databases db_name   ,  and in my.cnf (my.ini) defined - filter for single database , like -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db